# SAP cloud platform log files API

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform, xsjs

How can I download all logfiles from my JAVA / XSJS Applications without logging into SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit. Is there an API?

This API (https://api.sap.com/api/LogFiles/) seems to be only for SAP Cloud Integration.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the API for the SAP Cloud Platform account itself: https://api.sap.com/package/SAPHCPPlatformAPIs (your link is indeed just for the [SAP Cloud Platform Integration](https://api.sap.com/package/CloudIntegrationAPI)).

All APIs for different SAP Cloud Platform services can be found here: https://api.sap.com/themes/SAPCloudPlatformService